# where to place the php & html files when building Phonegap app and how to make ajax calls for them

Tags: php, cordova

I am trying to build Android App for the existing PHP web application using PhoneGap. I have PHP files for logic and HTML files for rendering the UI. These files are placed in Webserver (Wampserver) in my system. Now I have seen some of the sources, which was saying -> make Ajax calls to PHP files which are in webserver from phonegap project. Based on that i created a index.html file which has Ajax call to the target txt.php file and tried to run on Android Virtual Device Manager. I see the index.html get loaded onto AVD, i have given some input in textarea and clicked on 'save message' button. but i don't see any response on AVD. Can anyone please guide me on how to place all these HTML fils, php files and how to make ajax calls.. I hope this question would help lot many beginners like me..

As of now, the below code is named as index.html and placed in assets/www/index.html of Phonegap project. I am loading the index.html page using

```
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Index.html page looks like this..

```
 <html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>

function chk_length(myform)
{
    maxLen=767;
    if(myform.txt.value.length>=maxLen)
    {
        alert('You Reached max Length in text area');
        myform.txt.value=myform.txt.value.substring(0,maxLen);
    }
    else
    {
        myform.num.value=maxLen-myform.txt.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
<script>                          
    function myCall() {
        $.ajax({
                    url: "localhost:8080/yours/txt.php",
                    type: "POST",            
                    dataType: "html"
                });


         }

</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="green">

<form name="myform" method="POST">

<p style="align=:center"> <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="txt" id="txt" onclick=chk_length(this.form); onkeypress=chk_length(this.form); ></textarea></p>
<input style="background-color:Yellow" size="4" name="num"> <i style="color:yellow"> Characters left</i><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save Message" id="Save" name="button" onclick="myCall()"  onmouseover=chk_length(this.form);>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the txt.php page which is placed in webserver (Wampserver) location of my system looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $txt=$_POST['txt'];
    $dt=date("y/m/d");
    $button=$_POST['button'];

    echo "$txt";
    include("pg2.php");
?>
<p style="color:orange">* Max 767 characters only *</p>

<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_query("create database mydb");
    mysql_select_db('mydb');
    $querys="create table mydb.events(edate Date,event varchar(767), UNIQUE(event))";
    mysql_query($querys);

    mysql_query('create table mydb.like(edate Date,likes varchar(767),UNIQUE(likes))');
    if($button=="Save Message")
    {
        if($txt!="")
        {
            $quer="insert into mydb.events(edate,event) values('$dt','$txt')";
            $quer=str_replace("\r\n"," ",$quer);
            if(mysql_query($quer))
            {
                $file=fopen('./backup.txt','a');
                fputs($file,$quer."; \r\n");
                fclose($file);
            }
            $num=mysql_affected_rows();
            //echo "$num rows affected"; 
        }
        $query="select * from mydb.events";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<table>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
?>
    <tr><td><p style="color:yellow"><?php print("$row[0]"); echo ":";  ?></p></td><td><p style="color:yellow"><?php print("$row[1]"); echo "<br>------------------------------<br>";  ?></p></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
if($button=="Like it")
{

    if($txt!="")
    {

        $quer1="insert into mydb.like(edate,likes) values('$dt','$txt')";
        $quer1=str_replace("\r\n"," ",$quer1);
        if(mysql_query($quer1))
        {
            $file=fopen('./backup.txt','a');
            fputs($file,$quer1."; \r\n");
            fclose($file);
        }
        $num=mysql_affected_rows();

}
$query2="select * from mydb.like";
$results=mysql_query($query2);
?>
<table>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_row($results))
{

?>
<tr><td><p style="color:yellow"><?php print($rows[0]); echo ":";  ?></p></td><td><p style="color:yellow"><?php print("$rows[1]"); echo "<br>------------------------------ <br>"; ?></p></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ha ha got it :) There is nothing extra work to do load PHP application on to android mobile... keep all your resources like html, php and images, css etc.. all in your webserver and make sure that webserver will allow others to access.. Thats it you just need to have the following snippet in mainActivity.java of your phonegap application..

```
package com.example.mobility;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.loadUrl("http://IPAddress:port/folder_name/index.html");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

You are done !!

Note: don't create such code which i have presented in question.. its useless...